# Error: /bin/bash: matlab: command not found when try to start matlab from a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, bash, matlab, jupyter-notebook

i'm new here and i'm a bit frustrated cause of the in the title mentioned error. Probably it's something easy but i'm a linux beginner...
I use Linux Mint 20.3, have installed Jupyter notebook via anaconda.

I try to start a matlab file from a jupyter notebook via:
`!MATLAB`
and get the error:

/bin/bash: MATLAB: command not found

I tried to set a new environmental variable in the linux shell via:

```
echo "alias MATLAB=/home/strom/Documents/MATLAB/bin/matlab" >> ~/.bashrc
```

like i found on this site:
https://www.cdslab.org/paramonte/notes/troubleshooting/bash-matlab-command-not-found/

Now i can start Matlab when i type `MATLAB` i the shell, but not via jupyter notebook.

Thannks for your help!

Comment: just to make sure, did you restart jupyter notebook in a NEW SHELL after adding this alias?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an alias here, instead, try modifying your PATH to include the folder with the matlab binary, by writing this in your .bashrc instead.:

```sh
export PATH = $PATH:"/home/strom/Documents/MATLAB/bin/"
```

After that, the problem should be resolved after logging out and back in or after rebooting your PC.

If you then launch Jupyter, the PATH variable is changed, making Jupyter search for matlab in `/home/strom/Documents/MATLAB/bin/`, where it is located.

Comment: Hello @Jonathan Zeller, thank you for your answer. i tried it but unfortunately it didnt't work. When i write 'matlab' in the shell it says: bash: home/strom/Documents/MATLAB/bin: No such file or directory.

Comment: @strom are you sure you copied the path correctly? Your comment says "home/strom...", however, since this is an absolute path, you need to put a leading / in front of it: "/home/strom/...".

Comment: Now it worked, i had to use: 'unalias matlab'